# Is Digital Topology the simplest way to achieve image compression for digital images?

Tags: metric-spaces, soft-question, fixed-point-theorems

**Context**

Currently, I am a high school student working towards completing my IB diploma program, which includes a component called the Extended Essay. The extended essay is an in-depth study of a focused topic chosen from the list of available Diploma Programme subjects for the session in question. Some of which include Mathematics, Physics, History, etc. For my Extended Essay, I have chosen to conduct an in-depth study on the Banach fixed-point theorem and its application to digital image compression. I have already conducted significant research on this topic and have reached the halfway point in my draft.

Here are some of the main sources which I have been consulting:

1. [Banach Fixed Point Theorem For Digital Images](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/271444147_Banach_Fixed_Point_Theorem_for_Digital_Images)
2. [Application Of Fixed Point Theorem for Digital Images](https://www.journalijar.com/article/39950/application-of-fixed-point-theorem-for-digital-images/)

**The problem**

However, I am facing challenges in progressing with my writing, particularly when it comes to discussing the mathematics involved in image compression. My research indicates that I need to understand digital topology to properly address the mathematical aspects. Unfortunately, I have never studied Topology before, and with less than a month remaining before the draft essay is due, I find myself in a difficult situation.

After reviewing the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_topology) and other sources on Digital Topology, it seems like this knowledge may be essential for my essay. Nevertheless, I am open to suggestions and wondering if anyone has alternative ideas that might be easier to pursue. I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions you can share.

Comment: What exactly is meant with "image-compression" ? If it is the Kolmogorov-complexity of a picture , then in practice pictures can usually be compressed , but in general, this is not possible.